# PixelList in regionprops

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I want to map the output of `regionprops` to the original image. What does the `'PixelList'` attribute of the output of `regionprops` denote?

When I try to access the pixels whose locations are specified by the `'PixelList'` attribute, they sometimes exceed the dimensions of the original image. Is this the correct interpretation?

Comment: I've added in the MATLAB tag.  This is obviously using MATLAB's image processing toolbox.  Consider adding this tag for future questions to increase exposure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26564917/pixellist-in-regionprops#comment41797545_26574194), you must verify that the **size** of `img1` is identical to `img2` otherwise you will have to transform the pixels' locations got from `PixelList` to fit them on `img1`.

Please note that the coordinates of the pixels in `PixelList` are given in an X-Y order, if you want to use them to index the original matrix `img1` you'll have to use row-column order:

```
img1( stats.PixelList(:,2), stats.PixelList(:,1) ) = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

What I have understood from 'map' is you would like annotate pixels in 'PixelList' on original image. Here is a sample code:

```
% Your binary image
im = imread('binaryImage.png');
stats = regionprops(im,'PixelList');

figure,
imshow(im), hold on,
plot(stats.PixelList(:,1),stat.PixelList(:,2),'.y')
```

Or you can put up some example image for better explanation of your question.

Comment: I did some transformations on the original image, thresholding and binarization, and then applied the regionprops command. In effect, i applied regionprops on an image img2 obtained from img1, and then am trying to plot stats.PixelList om img1. In some cases, I get exceeded matrix dimensions error. When I checked, the pixel values are larger that the total number of pixels in img1. But if I use PixelIDs, it seems to work out.

Comment: Yes, if you perform transformation its size will change and so will the locations. I think PixelIDs might work, have not tried.